# Counting Possible Ways to Score in a Basketball Game

Tags: combinatorics, logic

In a basketball game, a goal is worth 1,2, or 3 points. Given the score n of a team at the end of the game, we are interested in the possible ways the score n can be achieved. Write a function count(n) which returns the possible ways the score n can be achieved. 
Examples:

count(1) = 1

1

count(2) = 2

1 1

2

count(3) = 4

1 1 1

1 2

2 1

3

count(4) = 7

1 1 1 1

1 1 2

1 2 1

1 3

2 1 1

2 2

3 1

count (5) = 13

count (25) = 2555757

As I was trying to figure out the answer, I noticed that for n > 3:

count(n) = count(n-1) + count(n-2) + count(n-3)

**Why is that proposition true? I'm trying to understand the logic behind that.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ways to score the last, or $n$th point. There are three possibilities for this. We can score a $1$ point shot when we have $n-1$ points, we can score  a $2$ point shot when we have $n-2$ points or we can score a $3$ point shot when we have $n-3$ points. Regardless of what combination we use, we must arrive at one of these conditions(that is at some point we either have $n-1$, $n-2$ or $n-3$ points). So the total amount of ways to score $n$ points is just the amount of ways to reach either $n-1$, $n-2$ or $n-3$ points which by definition is count(n-1), count(n-2) and count(n-3). Therefore
count(n) = count(n - 1) + count(n - 2) + count(n - 3).